# Was würde im Antragsatzt gefragt "ggf. wohnhaft bei"?

Tags: meaning

Auf einen Antrag würde ich "ggf. wohnhaft bei" gefragt. Was sollte ich ausfüllen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich nehme an, das ist für Leute, die keine eigene Adresse haben, sondern zur Untermiete (engl. subtenancy) wohnen: hier ist der Name, der am Briefkasten steht, also der des Hauptmieters, einzutragen. Ansonsten kann man das Feld leer lassen.

Comment: _"Ansonsten kann man das Feld leer lassen."_ Oder _n/a_ eintragen um die Behördenhengste zu verwirren ;-)